# Solving $|3x-2y-11|+2\sqrt{31-8x+5y}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, radicals, absolute-value

$$|3x-2y-11|+2\sqrt{31-8x+5y}=0$$

I was confused at first as there are clearly 2 vars but only 1 equation, but the textbook does have an answer.

**What I tried:**

- Setting some bound by letting the ordered tuple (x,y) be a solution and then by assuming x *<* y create some sort of inequality. That got me nowhere.
- I then tried to do this "properly" and move the sqrt business to the RHS, square everything, simplify and end up with an ugly multi-var polynomial = 0. I could not factorise it neatly. I was sure this had to work but wolfram alpha agreea with me as well. I got stuck again.
  [image]

Please need a a new idea, approach or hint. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: you have a sum of two terms, neither of which can be negative, yet the sum turns out to be zero.

Comment: Hint $x=7, y=5$ (you have to do the procedure)

Comment: you have to solve the system of two equations $31-8x+5y=0, 3x-2y-11=0$.

Comment: dxiv you're a legend. I just did the simultaneous equations and got (7,5). Sad part is that my very very first answer was no real sols because I moved the radical to the RHS and saw that |f(x)| = -stuff and was like hang on... I completely forgot that if they equal zero, then it totally works lol.

Comment: @the Glad it helped. One thing to remember is that whenever you square an equation you *must* add the condition that both sides have the same sign, otherwise squaring will introduce extraneous solutions.